# What are the good free mouse and keyboard automation programs?

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation

I know about autoit and about autohotkey but I am not sure that they are the same.
What other good automation programs are there?
Should I use different programs for automatic **browser** mouse clicks and keyboard pressing?

Comment: Are you looking for a browser UI test framework or just a convenient way to click something?

Comment: A browser UI test framework

Comment: are you talking about record and replay programs or the ability to write your own automation ?

Comment: ability to write my own automation

Answer (score 3):

A Google search with the keywords "browser test automation framework" will yield many links for you to check.  These frameworks usually handle mouse clicks *and* keyboard pressing.  I do not recommend using different software for automating mouse clicks than for automating keyboard pressing.  If you believe you have special needs that would motivate doing so, you should alter your question to describe those needs.

Two frameworks frequently mentioned in this forum are [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) and [Watir](http://watir.com/).

Comment: BTW, apparently Watir/Selenium will have better interoperability in the near future. So you'll get the benefit of Selenium's webdriver and Watir's natural language syntax.

Comment: What about javascript itself?  can i use it also as a script language for mouseclick and keystroke?

Comment: If you want to code your tests in Javascript, you might want to look at this: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs

Answer (score 3):

if you just want to emulate mouse clicks and keyboard keystrokes have a look @ **selenium IDE** its an addon for firefox it should cover your needs.
 If you want to test the same scenarios in other browsers you can export your tests and run them under selenium webdriver

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out TestApi at http://testapi.codeplex.com/

Also, automation frameworks emulate key presses or mouse clicks via messages directly to the OS which bypasses the keyboard and mouse hardware & drivers.

Answer (score 0):

You might wish to investigate the freeware versions of iOpus iMacros.

http://www.iopus.com/imacros/compare/all/